# UI Kit how to center input vertically in a uk-grid

Tags: html, css, uikit

I want to vertically  center the input  inside a UI Kit grid, the button is centered, but not the input, i can see that both are display inline-block.

```
<div class="uk-grid">   
    <div class="uk-width-1-2" >
        <input style="height: 50px" placeholder="email" name="Password" id="password-connexion" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-1-2 connexion-bar-item">
        <button class="uk-button" name="submit">CONNEXION</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your divs are a specific size you can set the line-height within the div to be the same as the div height:

```
<div class="uk-width-1-2" style="height: 200px; line-height: 200px;">
    <input style="height: 50px" placeholder="email" name="Password" id="password-connexion" type="text" />
</div>
```

Or if your divs are of unknown size, use padding and transform to move it to the centre:

```
<div class="uk-width-1-2" style="position: relative;">
    <input style="height: 50px; position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);" placeholder="email" name="Password" id="password-connexion" type="text" />
</div>
```